# Definition of Multi-threading

Tags: multithreading

Not really programming related this question, but I still hope it fits somehow here :).
I wrote the following sentence in my work:

```
Mulitthreading refers to the ability of an OS to subdivide an application into
threads, where each of the them are capable to execute independently.
```

I was told, that this definition of thread is too narrow. I am not really sure why this is the case, could somebody be so kind to explain me what I missed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is the application that decides when to create threads, not the OS.  Also, you may want to mention that threads share address space, while each process has its own.

Comment: thanks matthew, the information with the address space follows in the next sentence ;).

Answer (score 0):

A thread fundamentally, is a saved execution context - a set of saved registers and a stack, that you can resume and continue execution of. This thread can be executed on a processor (these days, many machines of course can execute multiple threads at the same time).

The critical aspect of "multi-threading" is, that an operating system can emulate execution of many threads at the same time, by preempting (stopping) a thread once it has run for a certain amount of time (a "quantum"), then scheduling another thread to run, based on a certain algorithm that is OS-specific.